# Powershell Computer name Output

Tags: powershell

I been trying to run this script for a while but i don't seem to be able to achieve what i want. I have a computer list that power shell is pointing to and will like to use it to recollect computer information and so far i think i got it but for some reason is not outputting the systems name.

```js
$computers = Get-Content 'C:\New folder\computers.csv'

$Computers | Get-ComputerInfo | select SystemName, WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion | Format-List
```

this is the output

```html
SystemName         : 
WindowsProductName : Windows 10 Enterprise
WindowsVersion     : 1909
```

Comment: `SystemName` is not a property of `ComputerInfo`. What value are you trying to display here? Maybe `OsName`?

Comment: well the system name assigned to that workstation such as "DL45634" etc..

Comment: Probably `CsName`?

Comment: that one returns with my own system name unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemName is not a property of ComputerInfo. You probably mean `CsName`.

Also, `Get-ComputerInfo` returns information about the *current* machine. You have to use remoting:

```
Get-Content 'C:\New folder\computers.csv' | foreach {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ComputerInfo CsName, WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion
    }
}
```

(Note: For csv, consider using `Import-Csv` instead.)

Comment: unfortunately that did not worked either.. i'm trying to export the list of assets from that excel spreadsheet and collect the os version such as 1709.. etc and include the system name on the output.

Comment: @Eslendil You're not really specific what you mean by "System Name". Run the cmdlet, look at the output, and then pick the property that you want.

Comment: sorry I'm no that much of an expert in the subject still learning.. i want to add the computer name? like the one was assigned when it was imaged such as CL45564, CL45561 etc..

Comment: @Eslendil Yes, that should be CsName. What about my code did not work for you?

Comment: getting an error message connecting to the remote server failed. but for some reason still outputs some of the data for some of the workstations listed on that spreadsheet.

Comment: @Eslendil Powershell remoting must be enabled on the remote machines. But that's a whole other topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: okey i could enable remote powershell and try again.

Comment: i tried this one  Get-Content 'C:\New folder\computers.csv' | Get-ComputerInfo | select CsName, WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion | Format-List, but is also only outputting the name of my computer